# Why Ionic returns No Provider for File

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic2

After spent a lot of time on forums, any hint for :

Runtime Error
Error in 0:0 caused by : No provider for File!

In my app.module.ts :

```
....
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
....
....
  providers: [
StatusBar,
SplashScreen,
File,
{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
]
```

In a Service Provider...

```
@Component({
    providers: [File]
})
```

When app launch have the above error message...

Do some updates as "ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file" but nothing...

Any idea ?

Regards

JL

Answer (score 0):

Update ionic

```
npm uninstall --save @ionic-native/core
npm install --save @ionic-native/core@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to install the file module as in the command:

```
 npm install --save @ionic-native/file
```

Answer (score 0):

in Ionic 5 the new naming is import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';

the ngx is missing, hope this helps.